# wrap phpThumb in a CodeIgniter controller method

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpthumb

On **Codeigniter**, I'm using **phpThumb** to generate images. I didn't use the built-in CI image library because it couldn't do the "zoom-crop" feature of phpThumb, which I badly need (ability to create thumbnails of the same size regardless of their original size/proportions, by zooming and cropping when necessary).

Everything is working fine except my images' `src` look so ugly:

`<img src="lib/phpThumb.php?src=../../upload/photo/file.jpg&w=100&h=100&zc=1" />`

I was hoping to make it look something like this instead:

`<img src="photo/display/file.jpg" />`

by wrapping phpThumb in a CI controller `photo` with the method `display($filename) {}`

I was able to do this using the built-in CI image library, but I'm at a loss on how to use phpThumb instead.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different PHP thumbnailing library (also called PHPThumb) and used it: https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki

Here's my CodeIgniter class:

```
class Photo extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function display($filename) {
        require_once('./lib/PHPThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php');
        $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create('./upload/photo/' . $filename);
        $thumb->adaptiveResize(100, 100);
        $thumb->show();
    }

}
```

Now my `img` looks better:

`<img src="photo/display/file.jpg" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the apache web server then apache will try to serve up an image if a url with a .jpg extension is requested. So you can do this 2 ways:

1) Change your .htaccess file to tell apache to route all requests to a specific image name within a folder to a controller/method in your CI app which does the phpThumb rendering.

or, better yet

2) Have phpThumb save the images to a location on your server instead of rendering them dynamically. Then you can just access the file name that phpThumb saves to.